# Mapping random points on a sphere onto a uniform grid

Tags: geometry, random

Say I had an arbitrary sphere that is covered in a uniform triangle mesh of N elements with each element having a unique sequential index.

If given the coordinates of a random point on the surface of the sphere is it possible to map the point to the mesh element it is contained in without using the vertices data of the mesh?

i.e find the index of the mesh element a random point lies on,

For example can the fact that the mesh is uniform be exploited in mapping the point to a particular element.

Either analytical or approximate methods would be of interest.

### Further information

An example of a uniform triangle mesh on a sphere :

[image: Triangle mesh of sphere]

Comment: What's a uniform triangle mesh on a sphere (other than that of a tetrahedron, octahedron or icosahedron)?

Comment: Unfortunately the example doesn't make it less mysterious what you might mean by a uniform mesh. It's uniform neither with respect to distances between the vertices, nor with respect to topology. In what sense is it uniform?

Comment: I have added an image of the triangle mesh to the question. It doesn't necessarily have to be a triangle mesh the point is mapped to triangles have just been what I have been playing around with. An approximation could even use overlapping circles as the elements whose centres are uniform points on the sphere.

Comment: I believe it is uniform in terms of the triangle area. Perhaps uniform is not the best word to describe the underlying mesh however I suspect the solution will make use of some type of uniform division of the sphere surface.

Comment: [This is a pretty tough problem](http://packinon.sourceforge.net/py_progs/pg_saff.html). Also consider [this article](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF03024331).

Comment: Just a random idea. Is there any projection of the sphere (eliminating some points) on the plan that preserve the regularity of the triangularization ? if so, I think the problem will become a simple coordinate change.

Answer (score 1):

Without any claims to optimality, a feasible solution would be

1. Divide the latitude range $[-90°, 90°]$ into equal steps, forming a set of equidistant rings around your sphere.
2. For every such ring, divide the longitude range $[-180°, 180°)$ into steps such that each quadrilateral formed will have almost equal side lengths.

Using these, you could compute the coordinates of the quadrilateral for a given point from the latitude and longitude of that point, simply by multiplying them with a constant and rounding afterwards.

This idea was inspired by Figure 3 of [the paper](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03024331) [Raskolnikov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3567/raskolnikov) mentioned in [a comment above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386476/mapping-random-points-on-a-sphere-onto-a-uniform-grid#comment827103_386476).

Comment: Wouldn't diving the latitude range into equal sets cause a concentration of elements at the poles?

Comment: @cubiclewar: If you have fewer points in the smaller rings, then no such concentration should occur. As a consequence of this, the corners of two adjacent rings will not coincide for most quads. When you turn spherical quads into planar ones, this could turn out to be a very serious problem, so it might be that this makes my approach useless to you. If you'd prefer that, I can delete it.