# Spherical object with n vertices and no coordinate singularities

Tags: computer-science, coordinate-systems, geometry

I'm programming a tool where I want to track the directions of a unit vector. I want to store the position to which the vector is pointing on a unit ball. Each time the vector points to a position $x$ it's (float)value is increased

I'm using a radial gradient around the stored position to produce a small falloff, so I also need to access the "neighbour" elements. It is also possible that I use less tracking-positions(vertices) and round my tracked position to the next possible one .

Up until now I was simply using a 360x360-float-array, but since there are coordinate singularities I'm looking for an alternative

The optimal shape should provide:

- No coordinate singularities
- An arbitrary number of vertices, since I want to be able to alter memory usage
- Easy, efficient access to neighbour vertices

I already had a look at isospheres from Blender but I couldn't find a mathematical description and I asume the "neighbour-access" is quite costly.

Comment: If you could figure out the 'neighbour' relationship, a spiral coordinate system might help. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600801/evenly-distributing-n-points-on-a-sphere) on StackOverflow

Comment: See also [*Distributing many points on a sphere*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03024331) by Saff and Kuijlaars if you can get access to that. Learned about that in [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386476/mapping-random-points-on-a-sphere-onto-a-uniform-grid#comment827103_386476) and found it nicely written.